# PHP Session variables not preserved across pages

Tags: php, session

I'm new to PHP and I'm facing some problems when working with PHP sessions

Let's say I have a file (`index2.php`) with this code in it.

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['name'] = 'The User';
?>
<a href="index3.php">Click</a>
```

And this is `index3.php`

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>
          <?php 
                 echo $_SESSION['name'];
          ?>
      </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

For some reason I don't understand, `index3.php` doesn't show anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `index3.php` you need to start the session as well. As per the [official PHP docs](https://www.php.net/session_start):

> When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will
> call the open and read session save handlers.

Using your example, just initiate `session_start()` as follows:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>
          <?php 
                 echo $_SESSION['name'];
          ?>
      </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good advice but poor implementation. Session headers need to be set **before** output begins

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I'm aware that the session_start call has to be made before anything gets outputted to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you also have session_start(); in all php pages where you want to retain and work with sessions;

make sure index3.php contains session_start();